# digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length:evp_enc in C program

Tags: c, encryption, openssl

I am new to C program.Currently using EVP I want to decrypt the text.When I decrypt I am getting

> error as "digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length:evp_enc.c:533:IOT/Abort trap(coredump)".

Can anybody please tell me what is the problem?

And how to fix the problem

Here is the code:

```
#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include <openssl/engine.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/conf.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <string.h>

 char b64[] ="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";


int main (int argc,unsigned char *input[])
{

  char textToDecrypt[120];  
 unsigned char *key = (unsigned char *)"01234567890123456789012345678901";
 unsigned char *iv = (unsigned char *)"01234567890123456";
 unsigned char *ciphertext =(unsigned char *)input[1];
 unsigned char decryptedtext[128];

int decryptedtext_len,ciphertext_len;

unsigned char ciphertext1[128];

static char dec_temp[250];
  ERR_load_crypto_strings();
  OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
  OPENSSL_config(NULL);


b64_decode(ciphertext,dec_temp);

strcpy((char*)ciphertext1,dec_temp);

ciphertext_len= strlen(ciphertext1);

decryptedtext_len = decrypt(ciphertext1, ciphertext_len, key, iv,
    decryptedtext);


  decryptedtext[decryptedtext_len] = '\0';
  printf("Decrypted text is:\n");
  printf("%s\n", decryptedtext);

  EVP_cleanup();

  ERR_free_strings();

  return (0);

}


void handleErrors(void)
{
  ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
  abort();
}


int decrypt(unsigned char *ciphertext, int ciphertext_len, unsigned char *key,
  unsigned char *iv, unsigned char *plaintext)
{
 EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;

  int len;

  int plaintext_len;


  if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new())) handleErrors();


  EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(ctx, 0);
  if(1 != EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv))

        handleErrors();


  if(1 != EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx,(unsigned char *) plaintext, &len, ciphertext, ciphertext_len))
    handleErrors();
  plaintext_len = len;


  if(1 != EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx,(unsigned char *) plaintext + len, &len)) handleErrors();
  plaintext_len += len;



  EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
  plaintext += len;
  return plaintext_len;
}

void decodeblock(unsigned char in[], char *dec_temp) {
    unsigned char out[4];
    out[0] = in[0] << 2 | in[1] >> 4;
    out[1] = in[1] << 4 | in[2] >> 2;
    out[2] = in[2] << 6 | in[3] >> 0;
    out[3] = '\0';
    strncat(dec_temp, out, sizeof(out));
    }

int b64_decode(char *textToDecrypt, char *dec_temp)  //base64 decode
    {
        int c, phase, i;
        unsigned char in[4];
        char *p;

        dec_temp[0] = '\0';
        phase = 0; i=0;
        while(textToDecrypt[i])
        {
            c = (int) textToDecrypt[i];
            if(c == '=')
            {
            decodeblock(in, dec_temp); 
            break;
            }
            p = strchr(b64, c);
            if(p)
            {
            in[phase] = p - b64;
            phase = (phase + 1) % 4;
            if(phase == 0) {
            decodeblock(in, dec_temp);
            in[0]=in[1]=in[2]=in[3]=0;
      }
    }
    i++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encrypted values are bytes, not chars (though those have the same data type in C).  You're calling `strlen` on the cipher "text" but strlen isn't appropriate.  It'll tell you where the first zero is past where the ciphertext segment starts (which might not even be within the ciphertext itself).

You'll need to capture the true resulting number of bytes written from `b64_decode` and pass that as ciphertext_len.

Comment: Hi,actually exact encrypted value i tried is '6Mre/AoGu9bU+blvrVUL' and its should return '900000000123447891280000000' can you please tell me the changes in code